# how to use checkbox and input type number together in php

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I am creating a meeting room booking application using php. In that, when a person book a room there have an option to book tea or snacks and specify the number of items they need. For that, I use checkboxes to select items and input type number to specify the number of items.i.e, if tea selected you have to specify the no. of tea in the input field. My problem is that I can't store or display the checkbox value and associated number together.my code is

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="bookroom" action="bookedreview.php">
<h4>Food & Beverages</h4>
<div class="checkbox">
 <input type="checkbox" value="tea" name="food[]"><label>Tea</label>
 <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="coffee" name="food[]"><label>Coffee</label>
    <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="snacks" name="food[]"><label>Snacks</label>
    <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="water" name="food[]"><label>Water</label>
    <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="nuts" name="food[]"><label>Nuts</label>
    <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="breakfast" name="food[]"><label>Breakfast</label>
    <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="lunch" name="food[]"><label>Lunch</label>
    <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" value="dinner" name="food[]"><label>Dinner</label>
    <input type="number" name="foodnum[]">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="value">
</form>


if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  $foodnum=$_POST['foodnum'];
  $food=$_POST['food'];
  //$food=implode(',',$_POST['food']);
  foreach($foodnum as $index =>$value){
    $fud=$value;
    $num=$foodnum['index'];
 }
}
```

but when I display the variable I couldn't get the result. Can anyone help me how could store the checked items and the associated quantity together.

Comment: when and where do you want to save them? On a button click ?

Comment: "var_export" your "$_POST"-array that could help to find the problem, than you see how the form values are stored

Comment: Can you explain what **exactly** is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get with passing food name in textbox name array

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="bookroom" action="">
    <h4>Food & Beverages</h4>
    <div class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" value="tea" name="food[]"><label>Tea</label>
     <input type="number" name="foodnum[tea]">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="coffee" name="food[]"><label>Coffee</label>
        <input type="number" name="foodnum[coffee]">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="snacks" name="food[]"><label>Snacks</label>
        <input type="number" name="foodnum[snacks]">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="water" name="food[]"><label>Water</label>
        <input type="number" name="foodnum[water]">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="nuts" name="food[]"><label>Nuts</label>
        <input type="number" name="foodnum[nuts]">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="breakfast" name="food[]"><label>Breakfast</label>
        <input type="number" name="foodnum[breakfast]">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="lunch" name="food[]"><label>Lunch</label>
        <input type="number" name="foodnum[lunch]">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" value="dinner" name="food[]"><label>Dinner</label>
        <input type="number" name="foodnum[dinner]">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="value">
    </form>
    <?php

 if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $foodnum=$_POST['foodnum'];
    $food=$_POST['food'];


      echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'><tr><th>Food Name</th><th>Count</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
   foreach($food as $foo)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>".$foo."</td><td>".$foodnum[$foo]."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

    ?>
```

For Insert

```
     foreach($food as $foo)
            {
$fieldVal1=$foo;
$fieldVal1=$foodnum[$foo];
        $query ="INSERT INTO foodcounts( foodsname, cnt) VALUES ('".$fieldVal1."','".$fieldVal2."' )";
        mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, brother. Its working fine.. and is there any way to display the value outside the loop

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mean this.. what I meant is, is there any way to display it outside the loop anywhere in the webpage or whether I need to insert the loop where I want to display

Comment: could you help me how to insert it into database

Comment: There are lot of examples available for insert into database

Comment: no I am asking is when a person booking tea 10 and snacks 9 then how I insert it into databse with coma separator

Comment: as you mentioned in the code, then I need to make a separate table for storing food details when a person books the room, with the foreign key. right?

Comment: could you say me. is there any option to store it into an associate array with item as label and number as value